# Increase variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the JavaScript below to display number increment within set time frame. The problem I have is that I am trying to use them in two different cases with different sent values but they conflict with each other by displaying the same value. How can I use them in different cases without conflicting eachother. See code below:

```js
<script>
var START_DATE = new Date("January 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 8; // refresh interval in seconds
var INCREMENT = 6;  // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 25; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 $('#div1').html(count.toFixed(0));
 window.setInterval( function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    $('#div1').html(count.toFixed(0));
 }, msInterval);
});
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
var START_DATE = new Date("January 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 14; // refresh interval in seconds
var INCREMENT = 5;  // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 15000; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 $('#div2').html(count.toFixed(0));
 window.setInterval( function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    $('#div2').html(count.toFixed(0));
 }, msInterval);
});
</script>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

They are meant to display different output based on the set values but they are displaying same values

I will appreciate full explanation with example.

Comment: Because you're rewriting global variables shared by two separate timing functions.

Comment: @user3476168 Use `setTimeout(func, ms, counter);`

Comment: Looks like lot of unnecessary global vars. Use local vars and functions for this.

Comment: @ishettyl can you give an example with the code provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one function `countersUpdate` with local variables `msInterval` and `count` and parameters `elm, INTERVAL, INCREMENT, START_VALUE`

```js
var now = new Date();
var START_DATE = new Date("January 10, 2012 22:30:00");

function countersUpdate(elm, INTERVAL, INCREMENT, START_VALUE) {
  var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
  var count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
  elm.html(count.toFixed(0));
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count += INCREMENT;
    elm.html(count.toFixed(0));
  }, msInterval);
}

countersUpdate($('#div1'), 8, 6, 25);
countersUpdate($('#div2'), 14, 5, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: It didnt work, it;s just adding the total of INCREMENT + INCREMENT2 = 11, it picks the 11 and add to both output

Comment: @user3476168 refactored the code, taking care of local variables

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
<script>
   var count = 0;
</script>
```

What you're really doing is adding count as property of the window object, like so:

```
<script>
   var window.count = 0;
</script>
```

So when you embed these two scripts on the same page, the count variable actually points to the exact same property of the window object in both scripts.

You could instead set your own counter object that has two counter properties. Like so:

```
<script>

    var START_DATE = new Date("January 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL = 8; // refresh interval in seconds
    var INCREMENT = 6;  // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE = 25; // initial value when it's the start date
    var countersObj = {};
    countersObj.counter1 = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
      var now = new Date();

      countersObj.counter1 = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
      $('#div1').html(countersObj.counter1.toFixed(0));

      window.setInterval(function() {

        countersObj.counter1 += INCREMENT; 
        $('#div1').html(countersObj.counter1.toFixed(0));
      }, msInterval);

    });

</script>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>

    var START_DATE = new Date("January 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL = 14; // refresh interval in seconds
    var INCREMENT = 5;  // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE = 15000; // initial value when it's the start date

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
      var now = new Date();

      countersObj.counter2 = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
      $('#div2').html(countersObj.counter2.toFixed(0));

      window.setInterval(function() {

        countersObj.counter2 += INCREMENT; 
        $('#div2').html(countersObj.counter2.toFixed(0));
      }, msInterval);
    });

</script>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, still adding same value to div1 and div2

Comment: That will be because you are incrementing the two counters by the same amount at the same intervals. Not that they are still sharing the same var as they were before. This can be solved by bringing all of the var definitions that you don't want to be shared in the global scope, into the scope of the ready function. That way they will be local to that function.